# Why am I receiving a warning about deprecated code after installing Rakudo™ v2023.08?

Tags: deprecated, raku

After installing Rakudo™ v2023.08, I get the following error *every* time I run a raku command, either a script or a one-liner.

> Saw 1 occurrence of deprecated code.
> ================================================================================
>
> .pm file extension in raku library path seen at:
>
> file#/Users/jimbollinger/lib, line 0
>
> Please use the .rakumod extension for raku modules, or include a META6.json file that explicitly declares each raku module file instead.
>
> ---
>
> Please contact the author to have these occurrences of deprecated code
> adapted, so that this message will disappear!

`/Users/jimbollinger/lib` is a directory.

What is causing this error and how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know but my guess would be there's a file with a `.pm` extension in that directory, no? Hmm. I'll go try find the code generating the error...

Comment: I just tried [a global search of github for ".pm file extension in raku library path seen at"](https://github.com/search?q=%22.pm%20file%20extension%20in%20raku%20library%20path%20seen%20at%22&type=repositories). Gotta say MS is starting to improve GH search.

Comment: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/5278 says it all.

Comment: Well, not "all". But it's clearly the PR that has introduced the deprecation message. "it would be annoying for users that both A) use a non-META6.json library path and B) have perl modules alongside their raku files" might apply to you. And if so, so might "we have a few potential ways to allows users to disable the deprecation message". But "prefer to implement it later just so we don't have to bother supporting some additional public API that may not actually be needed" got accepted and the PR was merged without adding ways to remove the deprecation other than fixing the problem.

Comment: As to fixing the problem while there are no deprecation message disabling overrides (as discussed in the PR), my understanding is you "just" have to add a suitable META6.json to the library directory and/or rename `.pm` files that are Raku modules to `.rakumod`. As to the details for META6.json I think the right reference is https://docs.raku.org/language/modules. Beyond that I won't be able to help tonight; I need to go to sleep. I hope these comments have been helpful. Good night.

Comment: Having slept and read a little more, I see that [the 2018 issue that the PR resolves](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1846) is very important in understanding that the PR isn't just about performance. It's more so about better serving present and future Rakoons -- especially (but not only) ones who use Perl modules. Letting folk use the `.pm` extension for *Raku* modules means that, without a META6.json, no one can have *Perl* modules with that extension in their lib path loaded by `:from<Perl5>`. That's a self-inflicted wound against all Rakoon and Perl users, current and future ones.

Comment: I suspect a key problem here is lack of a document explaining what your options are. Please consider commenting on the original PR. Even though it's merged and closed, I still think it's a suitable place to ask for clarity on what you can do. If folk then point you elsewhere, that'll be progress.

Comment: Thank you, raiph.  I removed ~/lib from RAKUDOLIB, and everything works as expected.

Comment: As an aside, one should not use paths relative to cwd in e.g. `RAKULIB`. It is a security concern (someone could mkdir a lib directory and place a malicious module that runs on load). Additionally when precompilation takes place the absolute paths of the libraries are used in determining if a given repository needs to re-precompile code. When you specify a relative path the contents of that path will likely be different for different invocations (depending on your cwd), hence re-precompiling may occur when not needed. When providing library path you almost always want to use an absolute path.

Answer (score 4):

1. There seems to be a `.pm` file in one of your paths.
2. Some recent changes to Rakudo are beginning to enforce so-called 'canonical' file extensions within the Raku ecosystem.
3. If you're not in favor of this, open an Issue at https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues . This is an Open-Source project, after all.

Comment: "If you're not in favor of this..." Please note the comment I just added below Jim's question about the 2018 issue that led to this PR and its merge. I'd say the thing to post an issue about if you care, is lobbying for a way to *temporarily* disable the deprecation *message*, not the deprecation itself. I see about zero chance that the deprecation itself will be reverted, even if Rakoons who are currently using Perl would rather shoot themselves, and all other Rakoons, in the foot, due to a short term need to ignore the message. You'll be heard, but I doubt it'll be a sympathetic hearing!

Comment: There are new Raku users who don't have a sheaf of `.pm` modules from Perl5. Why make them jump through hoops?

Comment: I presume you've read the material about this, right? (The issue and PR.) Maybe add comments on which of the arguments given for it (reasons why to do this) then (in 2018) and now (in 2023) that you agreed with. And the same for the arguments given *against* it (reasons why not to do this) then and now. I assume you agree that there's a wide range of things to consider, a wide range of trade offs, so there's no right or wrong decision, but after 5 years I'm with the current decision; how about you? Also, why do you think renaming files is jumping through hoops?